# How Raspbian can control temperature by setup temp_limit in config.txt

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, broadcom

Just got a new Rpi gen #3, which has default /boot/config.txt has

```
temp_limit=85
```

I then turn that down to

```
temp_limit=70
```

after a reboot, it works. If you don't know how to stress the Pi processor, and how to read the temperature of that, feel free to clone my simple github code (shell script) and run that.

```
 https://github.com/Fisherworks/raspberry_pi_stress
```

I thought it's dynamic lowering frequency which can limit the temperature of Rpi - but using the following command, it shows the frequency is still `1200000`, which means it's running on full power.

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

Now the question is - How Raspbian control the temperature of BCM processor without reducing the freq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
vcgencmd measure_clock arm
```

And you can check if it is being(has been), throttled, capped, or in under-voltage by this.

```
vcgencmd get_throttled
```

https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/2295/runcommand-warning-if-voltage-temperature-throttling

return code is like 0x50005.

bit pattern:

- 0: under-voltage
- 1: arm frequency capped
- 2: currently throttled
- 16: under-voltage has occurred
- 17: arm frequency capped has occurred
- 18: throttling has occurred

update:
I know the command you used;

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

But it seems not used anymore and I found the new one being used;

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

You can use it or vcgencmd.

Comment: I've checked the second command line again and found it's not working in kernel 4.4.45:
`sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/cpuinfo_cur_freq`
but
`vcgencmd` is ok even in 4.9.11.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Naohiro. 
I got 0x50000, but still confused on the bit stuff, if the 0x50000 is a hex, then the bin should be 0101 0000 0000 0000 0000
so what you mean the bit 0 is the lowest one - the 0, and the bit 2 is also 0, which means it's currently not throttled? 
but the freq now is 600000, which is half of 1.2G - why it's not in throttling?

Comment: You can use these command/scripts:

`yes > /dev/null &       # to increase the load, enter it 8 times or more.`
`killall yes                   # release the load.`


`while true; do vcgencmd measure_clock arm ; vcgencmd measure_temp; vcgencmd get_throttled; sleep 1; done`

And you will see Raspi is taking rest when CPU load is lower.